# Expanding an existing data server

Tags: raid, storage

I have two storage servers available, both with an Areca ARC-1680-ix-8. It has an external SAS port available.

As I'm kind of new to this, do I just link both using the external SAS, after which they can see each other? Can I then build a raid encompassing all the drives from the two servers together?

Or do I need some other equipment to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AH, no - sorry, You can not use contrroller ouput ports to couple servers. This is like using a dual plug power cabel to run two servers without external power souce, because hey, they both have power plugs.

You can sue them basically to go to external storage compartments where you have lots of SAS drives in them (like some of SuperMicro for up to 72 discs).

Comment: Alright, that's kind of a bummer. What main-unit would I then need to talk to both of these servers? I guess that would be the fastest and cheapest solution.